# Should multivariate time series by normalized in any way before fitting a VAR model?

Tags: time-series, normalization, vector-autoregression

I have many time series on very different scales; some take on values in the millions, while some are restricted to $[-1,1]$. Should I preprocess them in any way, or will the found coefficients take account of all this on its own?

Comment: Unless you are making some kind of regularization on the parameters (which you probably don't if you are using standard TS libraries in statsmodels and R), no you don't need to normalize anything. You must make sure they are stationary tough.